# Get mobile data usage in Android 10

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-data-usage, networkstatsmanager, android-10.0

I'm trying to make a network usage monitor app, which shows mobile data usage history to the user. For this I'm using Usage access to get accurate data usage stats from `NetworkStatsManager`. But this no longer works in Android 10.

I'm using [`NetworkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager#querySummaryForDevice(int,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long)) which requires subscriber Id, which earlier I was able to obtain using [`TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSubscriberId()).

But the `getSubscriberId` is now not working in Android 10 as it requires `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` which third-party apps cannot have.

Any ideas on how to make it work? I understand the restrictions for getting subscriber Id, but I don't really care about the subscriber Id as long as I get the mobile data usage, for which I have enough permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `NetworkStatsManager` resolve subscriberId as follows:

- use `null` when running on Android versions 10+ (API Level >= 29) devices
- on prior versions of Android (API Level < 29) you should still resolve subscriberId (using TelephonyManager)

Here is a sample code that should help:

```
public static String getSubscriberId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            return telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Worked for me on Android API Level 29 and Android API Level 26 devices.

Comment: Yes, I confirm it worked for me too. I'm using Android 10

Answer (score 3):

Try passing `null` as subscriber ID in the `querySummaryForDevice` method .. That worked for me

Comment: It worked in my case. An Android 10 custom ROM based on AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way at the moment to get the information you want unless your app is a profile or device owner app. You can just use the `TrafficStats` but you can't use a query and it resets on reboot.